# Where is the setting for changing the appearance of armature bones?

Tags: armature, bones

In 2.7x and earlier, it was a simple matter to change the appearance of armature bones from the fat/bulky pyramidal shapes they default to, to some other form.  Where is this function in 2.8x?  I've been looking all over the place to try and find it with no luck.

Answer (score 3):

Same as before (unless it has changed in the latest versions?), *Properties* panel > *Object Data > Viewport Display > Display As > B-Bones*, etc.

If you want a custom shape, select the bone in *Pose* mode, then in the *Properties* panel *> Bone > Viewport Display > Custom Object* (and select a mesh that you've created for this purpose).

[image]

[image]

Comment: and who's Norbert...? :)

Comment: one of my secret project character  ;)